# How can I find the index of an object having a specific value in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

Since the title is not easy to get, I'll provide an example :

```js
var myObject = {
  "myArray": [{
"hashKey": "someHashkey1",
"data": "someData1"
  }, {
"hashKey": "someHashkey2",
"data": "someData2"
  }, {
"hashKey": "someHashkey3",
"data": "someData3"
  }]
};
```

I have "myObject" containing "myArray", and now I would like to efficiently find the index of the object having, for instance, the hashKey "someHashKey2".

I could build my own loop to check all elements in the array, but :

1. is there a built-in way to do it ? Something like indexOf() ?
2. is there a npm tool for that kind of need (I work in Node.js)
3. is there an efficient way to work here ? some bad way to avoid ?

[EDIT :]
My efficiency question is due to the fact that I will have to do this operation for basically all the hashKeys. I just found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-an-array-of-javascript-objects?rq=1) which has a "lookup" answer that could help. Still in the process of understanding it all...

Comment: What you have has nothing to do with JSON.

Comment: I am curious to know which way you have attempted...

Comment: why do you call it hashkey and does not use it for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an hash key I would recommend you to convert the array to an object and then you could find the object using the hash key like this: `myObject.myArray["someHashkey1"]`

```js
var myObject = 
    { "myArray" : 
       {
         "someHashkey1":{
          "hashKey": "someHashkey1",
          "data": "someData1"
         },
         "someHashkey2":{
          "hashKey": "someHashkey2",
          "data": "someData2"
         }
       }
     };
     console.log(myObject.myArray["someHashkey1"]);
```

Here is a small performance test for [array vs hash object](https://jsfiddle.net/4p1Lfq6L/1/)
as you can see there is a small difference between finding the same key in an array in an object. the object is a bit faster.

Comment: You're so right. With hash keys I'm better off that way. Only one question before accepting this answer : is there any loss in time efficiency when using your answer instead of an array-built structure ? (I'm not dealing with huge data, but I'm still wondering...)

Comment: lovely, you are my hero (for an hour) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [Array.prototype.findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to get index of every item you want.

```js
var myObject = {"myArray": [{"hashKey": "someHashkey1", "data": "someData1"}, {"hashKey": "someHashkey2", "data": "someData2"}, {"hashKey": "someHashkey3", "data": "someData3"}] };

console.log(myObject.myArray.findIndex(i => i.hashKey === 'someHashkey2'));
```

If search call happens most of the time then you can use this hash to check or access your values:

#### Old Fashioned way

```js
var myObject = {"myArray": [{"hashKey": "someHashkey1", "data": "someData1"}, {"hashKey": "someHashkey2", "data": "someData2"}, {"hashKey": "someHashkey3", "data": "someData3"}] };


hash = Object.create(null);
myObject.myArray.forEach(i => hash[i.hashKey] = i)

console.log('someHashkey2' in hash);
console.log(hash.someHashkey2);
```

#### New style

```js
var myObject = {"myArray": [{"hashKey": "someHashkey1", "data": "someData1"}, {"hashKey": "someHashkey2", "data": "someData2"}, {"hashKey": "someHashkey3", "data": "someData3"}] };

var map = new Map;
myObject.myArray.forEach(i => map.set(i.hashKey, i));

console.log(map.has('someHashkey2'));
console.log(map.get('someHashkey2'));
```

Benefit of using map is that it allows you store anything as key and not just string

Comment: @FelixKling I don't think that would be necessary. Isn't that description enought?

Comment: @mortezaT – A plain code without explanation is never helpful...Care to explain what is happening...

Comment: NOTE: findIndex is not supported in Internet Explorer as per the docs.

Comment: @TadDonaghe – OP is under context of `node` so IMO, Browser Support should not be the concern...

Comment: Thanks for this solution : I think this is the best answer to the question as I wrote it. However, I'm accepting a solution which makes use of my hash keys. Do you think it's a mistake to convert myArray into an object ?

Comment: @KLôN If you want to use your values as object then there is no problem but if you just need it for finding the one you want I wont suggest that if searching happens few times. BTW You don't have that object now.

Comment: @mortezaT : searching will happen many times. I'd say around half of the hashkeys will be searched by the end of the procedure...

Comment: @mortezaT : thanks a lot for your efforts, I'm taking some time to understand how all of this works !

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to get one (non-boolean) value out of an array, you almost always want `reduce`:

```
var index = myObject.myArray.reduce((index, record, i) => {
  if (index !== -1 || !('somekey' in record)) {
    return index;
  } else {
    return i;
  }
}, -1);
```

Or 'golfed':

```
var index = myObject.myArray.reduce((i, x, j) => {i || x.somekey ? i : j},-1);
```

Comment: reduce is not a good choice, because you need to iterate until the end, even if ther is a find in the middle or at the beginning. better use some.

Comment: @NinaScholz but some only gets you a boolean, not an index. And unless the data set is exceedingly large, or the function is called quite often on different data sets, I fail to see how the microseconds difference between this and a `for` loop with a `break` matters in the slightest, whereas this is a pretty clear win in terms of testability and compactness.